# How to add ":limit => nil" to schema without losing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I have the following Rails migration:

```
class AddTextToReference < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :references, :source_text, :text
  end
end
```

I now realise that `:source_text` also needs to be set to `:limit => nil`.

How can I add `:source_text` to my schema without losing the data stored in my `:source_text` column?

I am using PostgreSQL locally and for production on Heroku.

Comment: What makes you think you need a `:limit` on a PostgreSQL TEXT column which has ["variable unlimited length"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html)?

Comment: The default length is 255. That's too short for my needs.

Comment: For `:string` (AKA `varchar`) yes, but not for `:text`. You might want to look at the `\d references` output from inside `psql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `change_column` method

```
def change
  change_column :references, :source_text, :text, :limit => nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to change :nil to nil. I tried editing your answer in the same way but StackOverflow won't let me because apparently one-character edits are always trivial. Go figure.

Comment: had to change two symbols =) fixed